# What are the semisimple $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, semi-simple-rings

What are the semisimple $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

**Comments:** I think they are direct sums of copies of such $\mathbb{Z}_p$'s, where $p$ is a prime number. I believe it is, but I can not prove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $M$ is a simple module over $\mathbb{Z}$ then it is generated by an element. In particular, $M$ is a cyclic group. The modules over $\mathbb{Z}$ are precisely abelian groups, and every non-cyclic abelian group has a non-trivial subgroup (which are therefore submodules). Thus, the semisimple modules are direct sum of prime cyclics.

Comment: But $\Bbb Z$ is not simple.

Comment: @Berci You are correct, I fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

A semisimple module is a direct sum of simple modules. So we just have to determine what are the simple modules. A module $M$ is simple if and only if it is of the form $\mathbb{Z}/I$, where $I$ is a maximal ideal. The maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $p\mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is a prime integer. So the general form of a semisimple module is
$$
\bigoplus_{\text{$p$ prime}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{(\alpha_p)}
$$
for any choice of cardinal numbers $\alpha_p$ (where $M^{(\alpha)}$ denotes a direct sum of $\alpha$ copies of $M$).

Comment: $\alpha_p$ need not be equal to 1? For example, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not semisimple.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not the direct sum of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. The first group is cyclic, the second one is not (no element has order 4).

Comment: @Croos Can you write $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ in that form? On the other hand $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is semisimple.

Comment: Or on the other hand, a simple $\mathbb Z$-module is an abelian group which does not contain any nontrivial subgroup, that is $\mathbb Z_p$. Since semisimple $\mathbb Z$- module is direct product of simple $\mathbb Z$- modules, so it's just direct product of some $\mathbb Z_p$s

Comment: @YilongZhang Isn't it what I wrote?

Comment: @egreg Oh, sorry, I misinterpreted your answer. Yes, they are exactly the same.

Comment: I would just like to add something that is not very clear. $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are abelian groups, abelian groups with no proper subgroups are cyclic. Consider all cyclic groups. Infinite cyclic groups are iso to $\mathbb{Z}$, which is obviously not simple. Finite cyclic subgroups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, which are all simple.

Comment: @tmpys Are you sure about what you wrote? Finite cyclic groups are obviously not generally simple.

Comment: Yes, I meant finite cyclic subgroups that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ are simple and all others are not.

Comment: @tmpys And why do you think this is not clear? A simple module is isomorphic to $R/M$ where $M$ is a maximal ideal (left or right ideal if the ring is not commutative). The maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are…

Comment: I guess it is not clear to someone like me. Not an insult. I learned much.

Comment: when you said "(where $M^{(\alpha)}$ denotes a direct sum of $\alpha$ copies of $M$)" did you meant "where $\oplus_{\alpha} M^{(\alpha)}$ denotes a direct sum of $\alpha$ copies of $M$"? @egreg

Comment: @Confidence No, it would be $M^{(\alpha)}=\bigoplus_{i\in \alpha}M$

Comment: So do you mean that $$
\bigoplus_{\text{$p$ prime}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{(\alpha_p)}
$$ means $$
\bigoplus_{\text{$p$ prime}}(\oplus_{i \in \alpha_{p}} \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})}
$$?

Comment: I am unable to adjust what I mean in the above comment but I do not understand what do you mean by your notation .... do you mean that we have 2 direct sums?

Comment: @Confidence There is a summand for every prime and the summand corresponding to $p$ is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. It's a direct sum of direct sums. If you prefer, write $\bigoplus_{p\text{ prime}}\bigl(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{(\alpha_p)}\bigr)$

Comment: can you write it mathematically please? and why you mean that?