# Characterization of finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules with the property that each submodule is a direct summand

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

I want to characterize all finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $M$ with the property that each submodule of $M$ is a direct summand of $M$. I think the module has to be torsion but I couldn't say more. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230688/what-are-the-semisimple-mathbbz-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [primary decomposition of finitely generated abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Primary_decomposition). Since $\mathbb Z$ has subgroups which are not direct summands, you can restrict to the torsion groups. The groups of the form $\mathbb Z/p^m\mathbb Z$ with $m\ge 2$ have subgroups which are not direct summands, so your abelian group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p_1\mathbb Z\times\cdots\times\mathbb Z/p_r\mathbb Z$ with $p_i$ distinct primes, that is, isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p_1\cdots p_r\mathbb Z$ with $p_i$ distinct primes. (You can check that these abelian groups satisfies the required condition.)

Comment: Yes I also realized that, but thanks..