# Why $\alpha_p$ copies?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I was reading this question here: [What are the semisimple $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230688/what-are-the-semisimple-mathbbz-modules) and I understood everything except why we need  $\alpha_p$ copies here $$
\bigoplus_{\text{$p$ prime}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{(\alpha_p)}
$$
And not just $$
\bigoplus_{\text{$p$ prime}}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}
$$

Could anyone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second option would exclude something like $\mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/2$, which is a direct sum of simple $\mathbb Z$ modules and is therefore semisimple. The OP of that answer indexed the direct sum by the set of primes, so to allow a multiplicity like the example I just gave needs an exponent, which they denote $\alpha_p$. You could alternatively write this as $\bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb Z/n_i$ where each $n_i$ is prime. Then, for instance, the multiplicity issue can be handled by taking $n_i = n_j = 2$, for some $i \neq j$ in $I$, so there is no need to explicitly mention the exponent.

EDIT: Additionally, your second option doesn't exclude any primes either! It equals precisely $\mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/3 \oplus \mathbb Z/5 \oplus \cdots$, but this is only one example of a module. There is more than just one semisimple $\mathbb Z$ module, for instance $\mathbb Z/2$, which is not isomorphic to the above.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't exclude any primes either!"?

Comment: Are you saying that instead of writing "$$
\bigoplus_{\text{$p$ prime}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{(\alpha_p)}
$$ " we can write this $\bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb Z/n_i$?

Comment: What I mean is that $\bigoplus_{p \text{ prime}} \mathbb Z/p$ is one specific modules. There are no "parameters" to tweak, such as the $\alpha_p$ you mention. So for instance, the semisimple module $\mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/3$ is not of the form you wrote, as you must "exclude" the primes $p \geq 5$ from your list. And yes, I am saying that you can choose to write your direct sum in the form I mention, it's a matter of personal preference

Answer (score 0):

Because you can have more than one copy of a particular simple module in a given decomposition.

For example, $S\times S$ is a semisimple $\mathbb Z$ module where $S=\mathbb Z/(2)$.

In that case $\alpha_2=2$ and $\alpha_i=0$ for every other index.